# Turn off theme for Delphi 7 application

Tags: user-interface, delphi, themes, manifest, delphi-7

I had to fix something in a 20-years-old Delphi 7 application. After the fix, I thought I would improve the application by fixing the GUI theme, so I dropped the `XPManifest` component on the main form. Although this gave most controls a better look, there were some problems. For example, there are checkboxes and radio buttons with yellow text on blue background (*blargh*), and the black text color set by the theme rendered their labels unreadable. So I decided to delete the `XPManifest` component and rebuild the program to get back the original look.

Interestingly, the GUI theme remained after deleting `XPManifest` and recompiling the exe. I checked the DFM, and the `XPManifest` is really not in there. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the component does is add a unit to the uses clause, `XPMan` IIRC, that links a resource file enabling themes. Remove that unit from the uses clause to revert the behaviour.

This is a clear indication of the value of revision control.

Comment: Actually the code is under revision control, I just had some uncommitted changes when I tried adding `XPManifest`, so I couldn't use git to revert this because it would have reverted everything. I thought I would just put the component on the form and delete it when I don't like the result. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

The VCL was simply not very theme-aware way back then. A lot of VCL components exhibit bugs when theming is enabled, but not when disabled. Install [Soft-Gems' XP Theme Manager](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/windows-xp-theme-manager) <sup>1</sup> into your project. Not only does it enable theming for you, it also hooks into the VCL to fix a lot of the bugs, too.

<sup>1: Soft-Gems' code was eventually incorporated directly into the VCL, but I don't recall if that happened in Delphi 7 or if it was later.</sup>

Comment: That code was already integrated in Delphi 7. It was Delphi 6 that needed Mike's code. Anyway, this answers a different question and should be a comment.